# Подключение в модели базы данных

Tags: php, ооп

У меня есть `class Model` и в нем 5 методов.
В Главном классе я пишу `$model = new Model();` и вызываю метод
 
`$result = $model->checkQuestions($frage);`
И в каждом методе модели я пишу `$db = new Db();` что бы использовать `$db` и через нее делать `sql` запросы. Это бред. Как сделать так, что бы не нужно было писать каждый раз `$db = new Db();` ?

Comment: написать это в конструкторе, например, или другом методе инициализации. или передать из вне.

Comment: можно пример пожалуйста.

Comment: `public __construct(){ $this->db = new Db(); }`

Comment: Спасибо большое, теперь понял )